# Bootstrap: col-sm-6 expands above other columns on xs screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm experiencing an odd behaviour in Bootstrap where a col-sm-6 is expanding on top of the sibling column above it, which renders the sibling column unclickable.

Please see source code and live demo here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyMwod?editors=1000)

Resize the output window to xs size (below 768px) to experience the issue).

The checkbox for 'As above' is unclickable because the phyiscal address 'Address line 1' is expanding above it, creating a sort of barrier.

The issue can be solved by adding 'col-xs-12' in addition to the 'col-sm-6', but Bootstrap should figure this one out by itself without this (as it normally does). Any ideas what is causing this?

**EDIT:**
One could argue that I should put all my fields in different rows, but for various reasons I'd like to keep everything within one row and let Bootstrap figure out the flow of the items, which normally works fine.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>Postal address</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPostalAddressLine1">Address line 1*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPostalAddressLine1" required="" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter your postal address.">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPostalAddressLine2">Address line 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPostalAddressLine2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPostalState">State*</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="inputPostalState" required="" data-parsley-required-message="Please select the state from the dropdown.">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="nsw">NSW</option>
          <option value="nt">NT</option>
          <option value="qld">QLD</option>
          <option value="sa">SA</option>
          <option value="tas">TAS</option>
          <option value="vic">VIC</option>
          <option value="wa">WA</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPostalPostcode">Postcode*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPostalPostcode" required="" data-parsley-error-message="Please enter a valid postcode." data-parsley-length="[4, 4]" data-parsley-type="digits">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPostalSuburb">Suburb*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPostalSuburb" required="" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter your suburb.">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>Physical address</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-default">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="use-postal-address" data-parsley-multiple="use-postal-address">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <span class="text">As above (use postal address)</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPhysicalAddressLine1">Address line 1*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhysicalAddressLine1" required="" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter your physical address.">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPhysicalAddressLine2">Address line 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhysicalAddressLine2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPhysicalState">State*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhysicalState" value="NSW" disabled="disabled">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPhysicalPostcode">Postcode*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhysicalPostcode" required="" data-parsley-error-message="Please enter a valid postcode." data-parsley-length="[4, 4]" data-parsley-type="digits">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPhysicalSuburb">Suburb*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhysicalSuburb" required="" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter your suburb.">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not clearing your floats properly across media queries.

Add `.col-sm-6{overflow:hidden}` to see if it solves it, then try to clear your floats whenever possible.

Also, read up on [this](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), it might be helpful